# Is there anything wrong with how I pass pointer arguments?

Tags: c, function, pointers

The problem is not anything major, but I am unsure if I lack the knowledge to understand a specific comment given to me.

This is part of a assigment where I have to use pointers.

I recieved a comment from my instructor regarding a piece of code for the function `returnfunc` where  pointers are used.

The comments reads as following: "What input/output does the function have? The only  thing coming in is the judge points!"

I would ask for further clearifcation but the instructor is unavaible for the next 1-2 days.

So instead of waiting I was hoping that somebody could take a look and maybe determine what is meant?

The highlighted parts of the code is shown below:

```
//function declaration
void returnfunc(float *low, float *average, float *high,  float array[],int judges);

//calling function in the main function
returnfunc(&low, &average, &high, pointArray,judges);


//code for returnfunc function
void returnfunc(float *low, float *average, float *high, float pointArray[],int judges){

    float small =pointArray[0];
    float large =pointArray[0];
    float total;

    for(int i =0;i<judges;i++){
        if(small>pointArray[i]){
            small = pointArray[i];
        }
        if(large<pointArray[i]){
            large = pointArray[i];
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0;i<judges;i++){
        total += pointArray[i];
    }

    *average = (total-(large+small))/(judges-2); //average without largest and smallest value
    *high=large;
    *low=small;

}
```

`judges` is the amount of judges the user chooses.

`pointArray` is an array with the points given by each judge.

My interpretation of the code is that the input is the adresses of `low`, `high` and `average` also the `pointArray` and  `judges`.

The output would then be the updated varibles of `average`, `high` and `low`

Would you say that this is correct?

Comment: Post all code here directly as text as an [mcve].

Comment: Since the function return is type `void` you are not returning anything, so the only way you have of making any changes to parameters visible back in the calling function is to pass pointers as parameters and then update the values stored at those memory addresses within the function.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. My guess is that your instructor expected you to have three separate functions, one to find the lowest score, one to find the highest score, and one to find the average without the lowest and highest scores. This would allow each function to directly return a single result.

```
void returnfunc(float *low, float *average, float *high, float pointArray[],int judges)
{
    float small =pointArray[0];
    float large =pointArray[0];
    float total;

    for(int i =0;i<judges;i++){
        if(small>pointArray[i]){
            small = pointArray[i];
        }
        if(large<pointArray[i]){
            large = pointArray[i];
        }
    }


    for(int i = 0;i<judges;i++){
        total += pointArray[i];
    }

    *average = (total-(large+small))/(judges-2); //average without largest and smallest value
    *high=large;
    *low=small;
}
```

One nitpick: Why do you iterate over the `pointArray` twice with two `for` loops when you could do everything in a single loop?

One more nitpick: While `small>pointArray[i]` means the same thing as `pointArray[i] < small`, I think the latter better conveys the intent of the code.

And one bug: You don't set `total` to zero before you start adding things to it. You could set `total` to `pointArray[0]` as well at the beginning and then start the loop at one.

Comment: Ah. good point! Just to be clear though, would you say that I have the right idea regarding input/output?

Comment: You have the right idea on your ability to update the values at the memory addresses passed by pointer so you can have those updated values back in the caller after the function returns -- which I take is your intent.

Comment: @AliasaZarownyPseudonymia Yes. The way you did it is a perfectly reasonable choice. I probably would have created a `struct` with three `double`s in it. But that's a matter of preference.

Comment: @David Schwartz I assume you think of returning the struct of 3 doubles? I would not say that is purely a matter of preference since returning the struct imposes a higher load on the stack than the OP's pointer version.

Comment: @GermanNerd How so? Returning a struct just means a hidden pointer is passed.

Comment: @melpomene AFAIK, in C structs are both passed and returned by value. Of course you can write the function to accept and return pointers, but you have to explicitly do so. So where is the "hidden" pointer?

Comment: @GermanNerd On e.g. x86(-64), return values are passed in `%eax` (`%rax`), not on the stack. A single register is not big enough for most structs. So what happens when you return a struct by value? The compiler silently rewrites your function `struct foo bar(...)` to take an extra output argument, a struct pointer (`void bar(struct foo *_ret, ...)`). Return statements in the function (`return x;`) become `*_ret = x; return;`. Any calls `x = bar(...)` are then rewritten as `bar(&x, ...)`. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/kZMUuW).

Comment: @GermanNerd I don't know what you mean by "higher load on the stack". But it does seem to me that passing one pointer may be more efficient than three and, in any event, I trust the compiler/optimizer to do its job.

Comment: @David Schwartz I had assumed that you suggested to *both* pass in a structure by value, as well as returning one. If, of course, you intended to just pass one pointer to such a structure as an in-out argument, that clearly is more efficient and might not even involve the stack.

Comment: @melpomene While what you say is true, it is 100% dependant both on the hardware architecture and the compiler implementation. When reasoning about source code in general (C strives to be hardware-agnostic) I would not consider that useful.

Comment: @GermanNerd His min/max/avg parameters are output only, so I would have the function return a `struct`. This might result in passing a hidden pointer to the function, but I'd trust the compiler/optimizer to find the best way on my platform.

Comment: @David Schwartz Indeed, output only, thanks. That does not change much. Relying on optimizations seems to me more like the C++ frame of mind. When I look at C source code (without catering to a specific HW/OS setup), I try to think in the simplest possible machine terms conceivable or likely. Of course even the assumption that there might be something like a stack is unwarranted. But putting such assumptions on a scale, I'd say that relying on a compiler to optimize the always feasible true memory usage, regardless of the implementation, with register usage instead is treading on thin ice.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor apparently remarks that it is unclear what is input and output of the function. This could be improved in the following ways:

- It is a widespread convention that in the function declaration, input parameters are listed first, then output parameters. In your example that order is reversed.
- When using pointers as parameters, they could be both an input parameter of pointer (or array) type, or an output parameter. Since the C syntax cannot make this discrimination unambiguously, another good practice is to add comments above the function declaration, explaining the role and purpose of all parameters.

David Schwarz replies that he thinks your instructor may have expected multiple functions: one for the average, one for the low and one for the high point. From a performance point of view this does not seem attractive, since that would mean that all those functions must iterate over the points array, whilst one function could do it in one iteration. As already pointed out by others: your function could be improved by merging the two for loops into one.